# Visual studio 2010 no such file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

having some problems using a font library. Im getting the current error

```
c:\users\taylor\documents\uni\win32opengl2template\freetype.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
```

In freetype.h all of the following cant be found

```
//FreeType Headers
#include <ft2build.h>
#include <freetype/freetype.h>
#include <freetype/ftglyph.h>
#include <freetype/ftoutln.h>
#include <freetype/fttrigon.h>
```

However when i link them directly like this, it works.

```
#include <c:\users\taylor\documents\uni\win32opengl2template\ft2build.h>
```

So im guessing there is some sort of directory setting i need to change in VS, but i have no idea how to??

Comment: Right-click the project, Properties, C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories setting.

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread once ... looks like what you want

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/gametechnologiesdirectx101/thread/5d24f4af-a827-416f-b2e9-5bde479d6925/

As per the given solution:

Usually, if you install the SDK after you install your IDE then it will configure it accordingly.

> In Visual C++, go to the "Tools" menu, select "Options". Expand the
>   "Projects and Solutions" node on the left-hand side. Select "VC++
>   Directories". You should see a pane with a list of folders... Use the
>   drop-down in the top right ("Show directories for..") to be "Include
>   Files". Add the \include folder from your SDK installation. You might
>   want to add the \lib folder to the "Library Files" section as well.
>
> Click "okay" and you're ready to go!

**EDIT:**

Looks like the above settings works only in VS 2005/2008 and not in VS 2010. In VS 2010 this have changed. Taken from [VC++ Directories](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx) and it says:

### Changes in VS 2010

The first thing you’ll notice in VS 2010 when working with VC++ Directories is that they appear to have disappeared. When you go to the Tools->Options window and look in Project and Solutions, you’ll see the window looks very similar to the screenshot above – only VC++ Directories is gone.

> However, if you bring up a VC++ project in the IDE and open the
>   project properties window (right-click on the project node and select
>   Properties), you will notice a Rule called VC++ Directories (Rules are
>   the tree of selections on the left pane of the property page window)
>   and that the values you see are the same defaults that you would get
>   from VS 2008. Additionally, you can edit these properties in the same
>   way as any other project property (including using the macro editor as
>   shown – something not possible in VS 2008).

Comment: Thanks but it says directory editing in tools - options has been deprecated and isnt available?