# matplotlib fatal error ft2

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, installation

I have installed pythonxy on Windows 7 and an error occured after I ran

```
from pylab import *
```

which seemed to come from matplotlib, connected to the ft2font module. I tried to reinstall matplotlib by downloading it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.1.0 and running

```
python setup.py install
```

The installation aborts with the message

```
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:3:0:
src/ft2font.h:16:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
#include <ft2build.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can somebody help me with this?

#### EDIT: The answer below might still help somebody (for me even more errors occured and in the end I installed the Oracle Virtual Box. Now I run Ubuntu in the Virtual Box and everything works fine : ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the dev libraries for "freetype2", and doing so depends on how you've got your local environment configured.

This is explained in more detail here;

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm

http://www.freetype.org/download.html

It would also appear a similar question is answered here;

[Visual studio 2010 no such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507028/visual-studio-2010-no-such-file)

However this can be a tricky process and `matplotlib` recommend that Windows users use the "Enthought Edition" of Python which has many of these packages preinstalled;

http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#installing-on-windows

Comment: I have followed your suggestion: I went to http://www.freetype.org/download.html and the to the Freetype for Windows Page: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/freetype.htm and then chose the "Setup program". The installation finishes without error messages, but I get the same error message from matplotlib as before : ( I will restart my computer and see if this helps...

Comment: This is probably because the libraries are not on the build path, however it would seem there might be a quicker way to fix this. matplotlib recommend using the "Enthought" edition of Python which has many of these tools built in, see http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html . It also explains how to buil from source, but explains you have to modify files with build and include paths etc. If possible, using the Enthought edition sounds like the easiest way forward. Modified answer accordingly. Can you try this and let us know if it fixes the problem?